# Users with the Cancel Checkout permission can read and edit all items

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, item-level-permissions, sharepoint-permissions

When we create a custom list >> and we access the custom list settings >> we get this message inside the Item-Level permission:-

[image]

so what is this permission level exactly ? is it this one?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're correct. The Override List Behaviours permission allows users to cancel the checkout of files by others and allows users with this permission to override the settings shown in the first screenshot.